# Symfony2: user/authentication provider; password check

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, ldap

Out of the documentation of Symfony, I understand how the user provider and authentication provider should work. I try to implement my own user and/or authentication Provider. What i did not yet get completely, is how to compare/where to check the password within this System.

In the documentation [1] I can see, that the user provider shall return a user object, if the user even exists. But then, I can see, that if the user has been found, the user is in this example returned with

```
 return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
```

1. question is: Why is the user object returned with the password here.
2. question: How to retrieve the password in this class? Isn't this the task of the authentication provider? If so, how to check the password there?

There is surely a use case where this model makes sense, but for the time being, I do not see it. Maybe someone here has the background to explain this to me.

Background: I want to use LDAP for authentication. So my first approach would be to create a user provider who checks anonymously if the user exists through a ldap search and if so, tries to authenticate him. The thing is, that I cannot return a user object with password (but also other attributes which I only get when the user is already authenticated). The user will then be stored/cached in a local DB where user specific settings and attributes will also be saved.

[1] http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security system can indeed be overwhelming and it's hard to know where to start.  I suspect there may already be ldap bundles out there (hint) but it is more fun to make your own.

It's helpful to see how the standard form_login firewall is implemented.  The authentication provider is reduced to only two methods:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider;

class DaoAuthenticationProvider extends UserAuthenticationProvider
{
    private $encoderFactory;
    private $userProvider;

protected function retrieveUser($username, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
{
    try {
        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);

protected function checkAuthentication(UserInterface $user, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
{
       if (!$this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user)->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $presentedPassword, $user->getSalt())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password is invalid.');
```

So a login form has been presented, the user fills in user name and password, presses the login button, the form_login firewall intercepts the login_check request, does all kind of wonderful things but eventually calls authenticationProvider.retrieverUser which in turn calls userProvider.loadUserByUsername.

Your ldap user provider will then do a ldap search for the username.  If nothing is found then you throw a UserNotFoundException.  If the user is found then you wrap any useful bits of info and return a user object.  Password is irrelevant at this point.

More magic happens and eventually authenticationProvider.checkAuthentication is called with whatever user object was returned from your user provider.  It is at this point you would authenticate (bind) the user with your ldap service.  The plaintext password that the user types into the login form is available via $presentedPassword.

Once you have an authenticated user then things become a bit my hazy.  You mentioned caching stuff in a local db.  You will probably end up having to override the authenticationProvider.authenticate method to get your authenticated token built right. And you will probably need to train your userProvider.refreshUser to talk to your local cache.  You might even need to have userProvider.loadUserByUsername check your local cache before doing an ldap search.  Those are all details specific to your design.

You can use a parameter key security.authentication.provider.dao.class to point to your own authentication provider class from within the form_login firewall.  That in turn will let you get most (possibly all) of your ldap functionality running without having to build a complete firewall package.

Have fun.

Comment: Thank you. This was an explanation I was looking for. I am aware that I have to override some methods/classes. The LDAP bundles which exists were in use up until now, they shall be replaced by an own bundle due to our requirements.

Comment: (Symfony 2.6) One question, could you tell how to obtain user and password if I were using a LoginModel(username, password) and a LoginType (building those fields, the naming changes so...), where does the request stores the Token, different of symfony's convention (_username, _password), before entering to authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey), in my class LdapAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface. Thanks.

Comment: @Felix - Probably best to start a new question.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642719/symfony-2-ldap-custom-authentication-provider

Comment: In symfony 2.0, how can you overwrite checkAuthentication method instead of using DaoAuthenticationProvider->checkAuthentication()

Comment: @ytdm This an 8 year old question.  Might be better to ask a new question being sure to indicate which Symfony version you are really using.